# Conditionally displaying warning message captured via withCallingHandlers

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, tidyverse

## Background

I've a simple script that iterates over CSV files available in directory and reads them into one data frame using `read_csv` and `map_dfr` functions respectively. The script may encounter a file with missing a column. In that case `read_csv` will generate a warning, as I'm specifying the column names via `cols_only`, which I want to keep.

### Desired outcome

I would like to be able to run this script with *optional* warning displayed. I'm trying to capture this output by using `withCallingHandlers` and then, depending on a value of a function argument, present warning or do nothing with it and continue.

### Problem

The warnings are not showing even if `show_warnings` is `TRUE`. It seems like the `warning` element of the `withCallingHandlers is not evaluated.

---

## Example

```
# Notes
# Conditionally import files and glide over files with missing columns

# Settings ----------------------------------------------------------------

# Libs
library("tidyverse")
library("fs")

# Constants
pth_tmp_files <- path_temp("temp_csvs")
dir_create(pth_tmp_files)

# Files -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Create a set of sample files
while (length(dir_ls(pth_tmp_files)) < 11) {
    write_csv(x = mtcars,
              file = file_temp("sample_csv_", pth_tmp_files, "csv"))
}

# Add one 'damaged' file
write_csv(
    x = subset(mtcars, select = -cyl),
    file = file_temp("broken_sample_csv_", pth_tmp_files, "csv")
)

# Importer ----------------------------------------------------------------

append_files <- function(files_list, show_warnings) {
    csv_reader <- function(import_file, show_warnings = show_warnings) {
        withCallingHandlers(
            suppressWarnings(expr = {
                read_csv(
                    file = import_file,
                    col_types = cols_only(cyl = col_integer(),
                                          am = col_integer())
                )
            }),
            warning = function(w) {
                if (show_warnings) {
                    warning(w, immediate. = TRUE)
                }
            }
        )

    }

    imported_files <- map_dfr(.x = files_list,
                              .f = ~ csv_reader(import_file = .x),
                              .id = "origin_file")

    mutate(imported_files, origin_file = path_ext_remove(path_file(origin_file))) %>%
        arrange(desc(origin_file))
}

# Tests -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Should return data.frame(tibble) object without warnings
append_files(dir_ls(pth_tmp_files), show_warnings = FALSE)
# Correct    

# Should show warnings and return identical object
append_files(dir_ls(pth_tmp_files), show_warnings = TRUE)
# Object returned with no warnings
```

## Notes

- I'm mostly interested in making a proper use of `withCallingHandlers` and/or `invokeRestart` functions. I don't want a solution that uses `tryCatch` as I'm mostly interested in learning about other approaches to error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `suppressWarnings` inside your `expr =`  parameter, so no warning ever needs to be handled by your `withCallingHandlers` wrapper (actually `suppressWarnings` already uses `withCallingHandlers` internally, so it's also adding a layer of redundancy.)

The key is to invoke a restart with the restart condition "muffleWarning" if a warning message is emitted *and* the user asks for `show_warnings = FALSE`.

Incidentally, you will need to either change the name of your `show_warnings` parameter in the internal function or explicitly pass the outer function's `show_warnings` parameter to your `map` call - otherwise R can't determine which promise object it's dealing with.

```r
append_files <- function(files_list, show_warnings) {
  
    csv_reader <- function(import_file, show_warnings = show_warnings) {
        
      withCallingHandlers(
            expr    = read_csv(file      = import_file,
                               col_types = cols_only(cyl = col_integer(),
                                                     am  = col_integer())),
            warning = function(w) {
                       if(!show_warnings) tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning")
            }
        )
    }

    imported_files <- map_dfr(.x = files_list,
                              .f = ~ csv_reader(import_file = .x, show_warnings),
                              .id = "origin_file")

    mutate(imported_files, 
           origin_file = path_ext_remove(path_file(origin_file))) %>%
    arrange(desc(origin_file))
}
```

So now we have:

```r
append_files(dir_ls(pth_tmp_files), show_warnings = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 384 x 3
#>    origin_file               am   cyl
#>    <chr>                  <int> <int>
#>  1 sample_csv_1950b846938     1     6
#>  2 sample_csv_1950b846938     1     6
#>  3 sample_csv_1950b846938     1     4
#>  4 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     6
#>  5 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     8
#>  6 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     6
#>  7 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     8
#>  8 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     4
#>  9 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     4
#> 10 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     6
#> # ... with 374 more rows
```

and

```r
append_files(dir_ls(pth_tmp_files), show_warnings = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 384 x 3
#>    origin_file               am   cyl
#>    <chr>                  <int> <int>
#>  1 sample_csv_1950b846938     1     6
#>  2 sample_csv_1950b846938     1     6
#>  3 sample_csv_1950b846938     1     4
#>  4 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     6
#>  5 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     8
#>  6 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     6
#>  7 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     8
#>  8 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     4
#>  9 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     4
#> 10 sample_csv_1950b846938     0     6
#> # ... with 374 more rows
#> Warning message:
#> The following named parsers don't match the column names: cyl
```